# Azure deployment is stuck after docker run command

Tags: azure, docker, azure-rm-template

I am sorry if title is not properly framed.

We used azure custom script extension to do following :-

- Install docker
- pull docker image
- run docker image

everything works fine. but my deployment process is still in progress status and yet not complete. I am using ARM template for this. I suspect problem is that docker run is a continuously running application which does not returns to prompt, due to which Azure thinks that deployment is still in progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me!!!!

need to use run command with -d flag which will run it in detached mode.